# how to unbind a hyperlink for a label with the anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `label` inside the `link` tag. I did it for purpose to reference some other script. I want to remove just the `hyperlink` for that `label`.

```
<a href="/" title="Go to homepage">
<label for="enr_rds_batch_update_Section" id="section">Section</label>
<img alt="Look up Questions" class="image_section_search" src="/assets/Search-icon.gif" title="Lookup Questions">
</a>​
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not `<label for="enr_rds_batch_update_Section" id="section">Section <a href="/" title="Go to homepage"><button id="theone">Click</button></a>​</label>`

Comment: No, Actually i referenced for some other script to pick the label caption for some other pages. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Ok, I have a dialog box, I am referencing this label title which inside the link tag. So, i am just having the label inside of the link tag. Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you cannot have a button inside an anchor.

Comment: In rails, i have a image tag. For the example here, i provide the button instead of image tag. I edit my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the jQuery [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) function.

The line you care about is:

`$('#section').unwrap();`

Just put that in a place that gets called when you want to remove the `a` tag.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/6YSQQ/

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. I did a mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gromer, have one more doubt. I have a text_field. I am passing some values to the text_field. So, i gave a `readonly: readonly;` in style sheet. But whenever i click the value, its shows the text-box. i just want to display the text-box like a normal line without showing border, background or anything. Thanks

Comment: You can use a combination off jQuery's `.attr` and `.css`: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/dgSZH/.  Just change the selectors to do what you need.  Now if you want this stuff done on page load, just add a css class and attribute to the input itself, like in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/9Fv8G/1/.